# How to store datetime into sql database?

Tags: c#

I get this exception when I try to save a date into sql database

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type
>   datetime.
>   The statement has been terminated.

**SQL statement :**

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into tbl_purshaseOrders (po_currency,po_paymentTerms,po_deliverydate,po_projectId,po_supplierId,po_notes,po_expiryDate) values (@po_currency,@po_paymentTerms,@po_deliverydate,@po_deliverydate,@po_projectId,@po_notes,@po_expiryDate)", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

MessageBox.Show("" + dp_deliveryDate.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@po_currency", CB_currency.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@po_paymentTerms", T_paymentTerms.Text.Trim());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@po_deliverydate", dp_deliveryDate.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@po_expiryDate", dp_expiryDate.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@po_projectId", Int32.Parse(T_project.Text.Trim()));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@po_supplierId", Int32.Parse(T_supplier.Text.Trim()));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@po_notes", T_notes.Text.Trim());

int val = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
if (val > 0)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Added Successfully ", "Done", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, MessageBoxOptions.RightAlign | MessageBoxOptions.RtlReading);
   // resetFields();
   GetDate();
}
```

- `dp_deliveryDate` and `dp_expiryDate` are datepicker fields and have a custom dateformat `dd/MM/yyyy`**
- `po_deliveryDate` and `po_expiryDate` columns are of **datetime** data type

Answer (score 4):

You should extract the [selected Date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value.aspx) from the date pickers, not the text

Comment: Will this eliminate the need to specify the parameter type?

Answer (score 1):

Specify the parameter type:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ParameterName", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = "9/15/2011 11:30 AM";
```

Answer (score 0):

After modifying your code check this :-

```
enter code hereSqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into tbl_purshaseOrders (po_currency,po_paymentTerms,po_deliverydate,po_projectId,po_supplierId,po_notes,po_expiryDate) values (@po_currency,@po_paymentTerms,@po_deliverydate,@po_deliverydate,@po_projectId,@po_notes,@po_expiryDate)", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            MessageBox.Show("" + dp_deliveryDate.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@po_currency", CB_currency.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@po_paymentTerms",T_paymentTerms.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@po_deliverydate",Convert.ToDateTime(dp_deliveryDate.Text).toLongDateString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@po_expiryDate", dp_expiryDate.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@po_projectId", Int32.Parse(T_project.Text.Trim()));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@po_supplierId", Int32.Parse(T_supplier.Text.Trim()));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@po_notes", T_notes.Text.Trim());

            int val = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (val > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Added Successfully ", "Done", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, MessageBoxOptions.RightAlign | MessageBoxOptions.RtlReading);
               // resetFields();
                GetDate();
            }
```

Or

It would be problem of date format also check sending value format same as mentioned in column.

Answer (score 0):

The database doesn't expect that date format. Parse the string in the .NET code:

```
DateTime deliveryDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dp_deliveryDate.Text, "dd'/'MM'/'yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Then use the DateTime value in the parameter:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@po_deliverydate", deliveryDate);
```

Comment: @Amer: You need `using System.Globalization;` at the top of the page.

Comment: I got this error Implicit conversion from data type datetime to int is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Comment: @Amer: You have used `@po_deliverydate` twice in the query, and `@po_supplierId` is missing. You are trying to put the delivery date in the project id field, that is why you get that error message.

Comment: @Amer: Sounds like you're assigning the wrong value to the wrong parameter. Make sure the parameter data type is `DATETIME` in the stored procedure.

Comment: @James Johnson: It's not a stored procedure. The query is in the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only ever looking at the DateTime in C#, you could store the DateTime as Ticks ([see DateTime.Ticks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx)).  It's probably better to store the DateTime as a SQL DateTime object, however, so you can read and perform sophisticated queries against it in your database.